# How to find the maximum value of a column that is ordered by factors in R?

Tags: r, max, factors

So I have a dataframe with a column with the following letter grades: C C A B

I would like to return the value A which is the highest score, but when I run the following code it shows an error (that doesn't happen when I put numerical values)

`max(df$grades, na.rm=T)`

Note: I already ordered the letter grades with the following code:

`df$grades <- factor(df$grades)`

Note: Here's the data I used:

```
class <- c(
  "blah1",
  "blah2",
  "blah4",
  "blah3"
)
grades <- c("C", "C", "A", "B")

df <- data.frame(class,grades)
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please provide your dataset or a subset of your dataset (e.g. using `dput`) so that problem is reproducible and we can try it out on our own machines... thus increasing the chance that someone will be able to give you a quick and good answer. Thanks :)

Comment: thank you for the tip @mysteRious :)

```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: `I would like to return the value A which is the highest score` how is that the highest score?

Comment: look at `ordered` function this will enable you use the `max` function: eg imagine the vector `x=c(3,12,6,9,4,1)` is arranged from smallest to biggest. Just think of `1` being the maximum, since it is the last. Now given another vector `y= c(4,6,9,12)` which is the maximum? you just do `max(ordered(y,levels=x))` and it will return 4, since 4 is the second last in x meaning second largest  ie 2nd last in x after 1.

Answer (score 0):

Try `dplyr` with `magrittr` for the pipes:

```
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)
```

And then just pipe your data frame to the `arrange` function:

```
> df %>% arrange(grades)
  class grades
1 blah4      A
2 blah3      B
3 blah1      C
4 blah2      C
```

Or you can choose only the A's (or whatever you like):

```
> df %>% arrange(grades) %>% filter(grades=="A")
  class grades
1 blah4      A
```

Or even pick out only the classes for those grades:

```
> df %>% arrange(grades) %>% filter(grades=="A") %>% select(class)
  class
1 blah4
```

Comment: Thanks for your response :) What should I do if I want to get the maximum, not look for "A"...? perhaps there are only B's and C's

Comment: You want to find out the top grade in the data frame? Try `df %>% arrange(grades) %>% slice(1) %>% select(grades)` -- the slice takes the top row, the select pulls only one variable.